# Using the IQR method to filter outliers in experimental research, by group or as a whole?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, outliers, interquartile

In my current dataset (results from a factorial ANOVA), I know I have outliers (due to qualitative comments participants wrote during an online experiment), thus I'd like to do a filtering process to remove them.

So far, I have read that the IQR method is a good place to start (i.e., (i) find the interquartile range, (ii) multiply it by 1.5, (iii) from the top of the IQR, remove any data points above 1.5x the IQR, (iv) from the bottom of the IQR, remove any data points 1.5x beneath the IQR)

**Therefore, two questions:**

1. When performing the IQR method, would it be correct to perform the IQR method individually on each experimental group? (as we expect that the means/data distribution etc. of the DV may vary by group, thus what is an outlier my vary by group) or should I just perform the IQR method on the DV as a whole, ignoring the fact that individuals are randomized to different groups?
2. What are the preferred methods / best practices to remove outliers when performing experimental research?

Comment: it is questionable whether it is good practice to remove outliers from data **at all** by any such automated method.  You might use boxplots or the IQR rule to flag certain values as worthy of investigation, and subsequent removal if they are clearly erroneous (data entry errors, equipment failure, and so on).

Comment: Why not use the written comments as a guide to identifying the suspect data?

Comment: **On automated IQR:** I thought if I use an automated method, it would be less arbitrary: But you both say the preferred method is to investigate every row which the IQR identifies, and then delete based on the text comments which seem suspicious. **On the other question:** would you say that applying IQR on a group wise basis to identify outliers is fine? (i.e., as I wrote: I expect that the means/SD etc. of the DV may vary by group, thus what is an outlier my vary by group). Is my logic fine here? Or should I be applying to the whole distribution of the DV regardless of grouping variable?

Comment: It is easy to estimate probability models for which rare, extreme values are natural. So if the outliers really are natural, why not estimate a realistic model? Deleting natural data makes you estimate an unnatural model.